# Python Beautifulsoup accessing attribute in tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using whitehouse.gov to practice scraping web data. I have

```
    for a_tag in soup.select('span a'):
        categories.append(a_tag)
```

which gives me the a tags like below...

```
<a href="https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/./statements-releases/" rel="category tag">Statements and Releases</a>
```

Now I want to access just the "Statements and Releases" so I thought I would just do

```
   for a_tag in soup.select('span a'):
        categories.append(a_tag.attrs['rel')]
```

but this gives me ['category', 'tag'] as the output. I was playing around a little and figured out

```
    for a_tag in soup.select('span a'):
        for x in a_tag: 
            categories.append(x)
```

Gives me the output im looking for (Statements and Releases etc.), but im not sure why?

Comment: It is not an attribute you want. It is a property. The .text. And your inner loop will never be entered as you are already at the tag level so not sure how you got the output you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

for getting text inside a href, you should use text variable:

```
for a_tag in soup.select('span a'):
        categories.append(a_tag.text)
```

or

```
for a_tag in soup.select('span a'):
        categories.append(a_tag.string)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this is what you need:

```
   for a_tag in soup.select('span a'):
        categories.append(a.getText())
```

If you want `Statements and Releases`.

Whereas, doing this:

```
for a_tag in soup.select('span a'):
        categories.append(a_tag.attrs['rel'])
```

Produces the value of the `rel` attribute which is `category tag`